# Is it possible to access a list in a different (sub) site in a Workflow Activity using SPD?

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-designer

I have the following SharePoint 2010 site structure:

- Root (SiteCollection)

  - Queue (List)
  - Subsite (Site)

    - Target (List)

I'm using the custom SPD activities from iLoveSharePoint to create a site based on a template in the "Subsite" whenever an item is created in the "Queue". This works fine, however, now i need to create a new list item in the "Target" list aswell.

Since the workflow is running on the "Queue" list, it seems that I cannot access the "Target" list because it's in a different (sub) site.

Any ideas how I can resolve this issue?

Comment: I'm thinking this question may be exactly the same as yours: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/967333/accessing-list-data-from-a-different-site-in-sharepoint-designer-workflow

Comment: I couldn't find anything similar to my problem, but the one you linked is the same indeed (for 2007). Maybe you can merge or link these questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Kit that your question in the same as the one he references from stackoverflow, but I'll throw out an idea that wasn't offered for that question.

iLoveSharePoint includes a custom activity for executing a PowerShell script...it's certainly feasible to leverage that to do just about anything you can do with custom code...i.e. use that instead of building a custom SPD activity as the answer to the stackoverflow question suggests.

For reference: http://ilovesharepoint.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Execute%20PowerShell%20Script%20Action&referringTitle=Workflow%20Actions%20for%20SharePoint%20Designer%202010

Comment: I'd prefer a no-code solution, but this sounds like a very good idea. thank you very much :-)